# Securing a samba share

Tags: samba

I've got a samba share running, and can get to it from my Windows host.  Yay!  But that's with 777 permissions on the shared directory, which is no bueno.  Every example I can find either says to set 777 or just gleefully skips over who should actually own the directory.  How do I properly secure this on the server end?

And then, I'd like to make sure that Windows machines that connect to this share are, ideally, only allowed to add files... no reading or deleting or modifying existing files.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to #1 is 'force user = ', where username is, of course, the UNIX user that owns the directory.  In that case, 0700 will work.

For #2, making permissions 0300 accomplishes much of what I wanted.  I also have the shared directory owned by a group the owner is not in and set 2350; and 'create mask = 0040' in smb.conf  This way, this other group can read but not modify files, while the host(s) accessing the share can only write new files, but cannot modify or delete existing ones!